# D3 Graph not rendering when using Timescale

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I'm trying to get a simplified example of a line graph using dates to render but so far no dice. Simple integers on both axis worked fine, but moving to timescale broke it.  I've been reading through lots of examples but obviously I'm missing something fundamental.

Also, I'm using JSBin for testing, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
var h = 100;
var w = 200;

monthlySales = [
  {"month":"2016-01-01", "sales":20},
  {"month":"2016-01-15", "sales":14},
  {"month":"2016-02-10", "sales":20},
  {"month":"2016-03-15", "sales":60}
];

var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, w]);

var lineFun = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {return x(getDate(d));})
  .y(function(d) {return h-d.sales;})
  .interpolate("linear");


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr({
  width:w, height:h
});

var viz = svg.append("path")
  .attr({
    d: lineFun(monthlySales),
    "stroke": "purple",
    "stroke-width": 2,
    "fill": "none"
  });

function getDate(d) {
    var d2 = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse(d.month);
    return new Date(d2);
};

// get max and min dates - this assumes data is sorted
var minDate = getDate(monthlySales[0]),
    maxDate = getDate(monthlySales[monthlySales.length-1]);
```

Comment: Please provide JSBin URL to debug easily... i tried in codepen http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QEArPj  but couldn't replicate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scale's domain is being set with start and end values that don't exist at that point. It doesn't throw an error that minDate and maxDate aren't set, because the variable declaration is hoisted to the top. If you move

```
// get max and min dates - this assumes data is sorted
var minDate = getDate(monthlySales[0]),
    maxDate = getDate(monthlySales[monthlySales.length-1]);
```

to before

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, w]);
```

it should work. [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/jy14898/pen/qNYPaJ)